# Consider two ONTO functions $f$ and $g$ where $f(n)=\lfloor n\sec^2\theta\rfloor$ and $g(n)=\lfloor n\csc^2\theta\rfloor$ for some $\theta$.

Tags: functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Consider two ONTO functions $f$ and $g$ where $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\to B$ such that $f(n)=\lfloor n\sec^2\theta\rfloor$ and $g(n)=\lfloor n\csc^2\theta\rfloor$ for some $\theta$. If $\sec^2\theta$ is irrational, then which of the following statement(s) hold true

(A) $A\cap B=\phi$

(B) $A\cup B=\mathbb{N}$

(C) $f$ and $g$ are bijective

(D) $A\cap B$ is non-empty finite set

**My Attempt**

$f(n)=\lfloor n+n\tan^2\theta\rfloor=n+\lfloor n\tan^2\theta\rfloor$

Similarly $g(n)=n+\lfloor n\cot^2\theta\rfloor$

Now we have $n\tan^2\theta<n\cot^2\theta$ or $n\tan^2\theta>n\cot^2\theta$.

So as value of $n$ increases the value of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ also increases but none of them take same value.

This I could observe by putting $n=1,2,3,4,...$.

The correct options seem to be (A),(B) and (C) but I am not able to come up with any sort of proof.

I also tried to solve the equation $f(n_1)=g(n_2)$ so that I could get values of n for which $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ can be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r = \sec^2\theta$ and $s = \csc^2 \theta$ are irrational numbers, greater than one, with $1/r + 1/s = 1$, so that $(\lfloor n r \rfloor)_n$ and $ (\lfloor n s \rfloor)_n$ are a pair of “complementary [Beatty sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).”

[Rayleigh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence#Rayleigh_theorem) states that each positive integer belongs to exactly one of the two sequences, i.e. (A) and (B) are true, and (D) is false. A proof of that theorem can be found in the Wikipedia article.

(C) is true because both sequences are strictly increasing.